# how to pass a constructor parameter of a class in a different class main in C++

Tags: c++, class

//Class1 main

```
int main()
{
    ...

    Class1 obj1(parameters);
    Class1 obj2(parameters);    
    Class1 *Array[2];
    Array[0] = obj1;
    Array[1] = obj2;

    Class1 *Pointer = Array;

    Class2 repository(Pointer);   //where the error occurs.
}
```

obj1 and obj2 were created before and are class1 objects. class2 is a data repository class (Class2) I am trying to pass the array to it to point to it from Class2.

```
#include "Class2.h"
//what Class2 constructor looks like.

Class2::Class2(Class1* Pointer)
{
    tPointer = Pointer;
}
```

the problem is that I get an error saying 
`Undefined symbols:
  "Class2::Class2(Class1*)", referenced from:
      _main in Class1
ld: symbol(s) not found`

Any help would be much appreciated thanks.

Comment: @biz Are you building the source file that has `Class2` definitions?

Comment: @Mahesh yes I am trying to build it in class1 main() but it won't let me

Comment: As @Mahesh said,ensure that source file having `Class2` implementation is getting compiled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have quite a few errors, I'll try to show you how to fix them.

```
int main()
{
    ...

   Class1 obj1(parameters);
   Class1 obj2(parameters);    
   Class1 *Array[2];
   Array[0] = &obj1; // Array holds pointers to Class1, so you need to use &
   Array[1] = &obj2; // Here too.

   Class1 *Pointer = Array[0]; // Use Array[0] or Array[1] here

   Class2 repository(Pointer);   //Should be okay now
}
```

Summary:

In the line `Array[0] = obj1;` you are forgetting the address operator (same for next line).

The line `Class1 *Pointer = Array;` doesn't make sense because `Array` by itself is a pointer to a pointer, you want either `Array[0]` or `Array[1]` to make Pointer point at either obj1 or obj2.

Comment: @jozefg: I'm not sure I understand your comment. Do you mean `Class1 **Pointer = Array;` and `Class2 repository(*Pointer);`?

Comment: Well shouldn't `Class1 **Pointer = Array;` be valid? After all Array does contain a pointer to a `Class1` Pointer.

Comment: @jozefg: Yes, it's valid. But, in your first comment you said `i believe Class1 *Pointer = Array; is valid`, which is not.

Comment: OH I'm sorry, typo, please let me fix that.

Comment: I still got the same error is it because I misused inheritance? Does Class2 have to inherit from Class1?

Comment: @biz: No you don`t need inheritance, my guess is that you didn't add `#include "Class2.h"` to Class1 main (but you need to show more code to be sure).

Answer (score 2):

Ok so a few things:

1) Array is not type of Class1* it's of Class1**
2) You are making an array of pointers, obj1 and obj2 are not pointers at the moment! either dynamically allocate them or use the & operator to grab the address.

3) This is a suggestion: Use std::vector if possible. Working with pointer arrays can be a pain and get messy real fast.

But if you insist then go right ahead.